# Forcing SSL on phpmyadmin

Tags: php, ssl, phpmyadmin

I couldn't decide which website this question we be on (since I see it almost everywhere) so feel free to migrate.

I've set up a self-signed SSL cert on my server to secure my installation of phpMyAdmin. I've just installed it from source to the latest version (4.2.8) and now would like to force SSL.

In my /etc/phpMyadmin/config.inc.php, I've added the `$cfg['ForceSSL] = true;` property however this does not force any SSL. I still can access the site on port 80 as well as port 443.

On my other server, the property forced SSL with phpMyAdmin and I can also see it in the URL `?SID` which I do not see on this server.

Basically I want phpMyAdmin to redirect all http requests to https like on my other server.

Here is my config.inc.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * phpMyAdmin configuration file, you can use it as base for the manual
 * configuration. For easier setup you can use "setup/".
 *
 * All directives are explained in Documentation.html and on phpMyAdmin
 * wiki <http://wiki.phpmyadmin.net>.
 */

/*
 * This is needed for cookie based authentication to encrypt password in
 * cookie
 */
$cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'MUSTBECHANGEDONINSTALL'; /* YOU MUST FILL IN THIS FOR COOKIE AUTH! */

/**
 * Server(s) configuration
  */
$i = 0;

// The $cfg['Servers'] array starts with $cfg['Servers'][1].  Do not use
// $cfg['Servers'][0]. You can disable a server config entry by setting host
// to ''. If you want more than one server, just copy following section
// (including $i incrementation) serveral times. There is no need to define
// full server array, just define values you need to change.
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host']          = 'localhost'; // MySQL hostname or IP address
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port']          = '';          // MySQL port - leave blank for default port
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket']        = '';          // Path to the socket - leave blank for default socket
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type']  = 'tcp';       // How to connect to MySQL server ('tcp' or 'socket')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension']     = 'mysqli';    // The php MySQL extension to use ('mysql' or 'mysqli')
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress']      = FALSE;       // Use compressed protocol for the MySQL connection
                                                    // (requires PHP >= 4.3.0)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controluser']   = '';          // MySQL control user settings
                                                    // (this user must have read-only
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['controlpass']   = '';          // access to the "mysql/user"
                                                    // and "mysql/db" tables).
                                                    // The controluser is also
                                                    // used for all relational
                                                    // features (pmadb)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'cookie';    // Authentication method (config, http or cookie based)?
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = '';          // MySQL user
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = '';          // MySQL password (only needed
                                                    // with 'config' auth_type)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['only_db']       = '';          // If set to a db-name, only
                                                    // this db is displayed in left frame
                                                    // It may also be an array of db-names, where sorting order is relevant.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['hide_db']       = '';          // Database name to be hidden from listings
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose']       = '';          // Verbose name for this host - leave blank to show the hostname

$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pmadb']         = '';          // Database used for Relation, Bookmark and PDF Features
                                                    // (see scripts/create_tables.sql)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'phpmyadmin'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bookmarktable'] = '';          // Bookmark table
                                                    //   - leave blank for no bookmark support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_bookmark'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['relation']      = '';          // table to describe the relation between links (see doc)
                                                    //   - leave blank for no relation-links support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_relation'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_info']    = '';          // table to describe the display fields
                                                    //   - leave blank for no display fields support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['table_coords']  = '';          // table to describe the tables position for the PDF schema
                                                    //   - leave blank for no PDF schema support
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_table_coords'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['pdf_pages']     = '';          // table to describe pages of relationpdf
                                                    //   - leave blank if you don't want to use this
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_pdf_pages'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['column_info']   = '';          // table to store column information
                                                    //   - leave blank for no column comments/mime types
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_column_info'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['history']       = '';          // table to store SQL history
                                                    //   - leave blank for no SQL query history
                                                    //     DEFAULT: 'pma_history'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose_check'] = TRUE;        // set to FALSE if you know that your pma_* tables
                                                    // are up to date. This prevents compatibility
                                                    // checks and thereby increases performance.
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot']     = TRUE;        // whether to allow root login
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['order']           // Host authentication order, leave blank to not use
                                     = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowDeny']['rules']           // Host authentication rules, leave blank for defaults
                                     = array();
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']              // Allow logins without a password. Do not change the FALSE
                                     = FALSE;       // default unless you're running a passwordless MySQL server
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['designer_coords']              // Leave blank (default) for no Designer support, otherwise
                                     = '';          // set to suggested 'pma_designer_coords' if really needed
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_garbage_threshold']         // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = 50;          //   DEFAULT: '50'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_repository_threshold']      // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = '32M';       //   DEFAULT: '32M'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_blob_timeout']         // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = 600;         //   DEFAULT: '600'
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['bs_temp_log_threshold']        // Blobstreaming: Recommented default value from upstream
                                     = '32M';       //   DEFAULT: '32M'
/*
 * End of servers configuration
 */

/*
 * Directories for saving/loading files from server
 */
$cfg['UploadDir'] = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/upload';
$cfg['SaveDir']   = '/var/lib/phpMyAdmin/save';

/*
 * Disable the default warning that is displayed on the DB Details Structure
 * page if any of the required Tables for the relation features is not found
 */
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = TRUE;

$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;
?>
```

If you need anything else, do ask.

Running Centos, Apache

Comment: Can't you configure that on the web server itself?

Comment: Letting the application redirect is potentially insecure. It simply must not be accessible without HTTPS.

Comment: I could, but I was wondering why the application isn't doing it itself like it should? I will be doing it on the server side too, this is just a backup plan.

Answer (score 1):

You must wrap `true` in quotes in this last line:

```
cfg['ForceSSL'] = 'true';
```

otherwise it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why phpMyAdmin isn't doing that, but that should be a setting configured in the web server.

When you allow HTTP connections to redirect to HTTPS, you open yourself for MITM attacks that strip the redirection (see this video on [SSLstrip](http://youtu.be/ibF36Yyeehw?t=8m37s)).

If you *really* want to make sure that works, take a look at [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15715674/phpmyadmin-auth-method-and-force-ssl-not-working-as-expected) for a similar problem, but I would advise against it. If you could have port 80 closed, even better (although I figure a MITM could always intercept the SYN and still downgrade your connection to HTTP. Oh well...)

Comment: There’s also HSTS, so not all is lost. ;) If he doesn’t even try over HTTP, all will be good as well. Leaving HTTP→HTTPS redirects is necessary for lazy users, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Stop using that configuration value because it is deprecated since 4.6.0

https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_ForceSSL

Use `$cfg['PmaAbsoluteUri']` instead

https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_PmaAbsoluteUri